# Gson library error

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, gson

I get this error when I use the gson library. I couldn't find much information about this error when searching on Google.

Can you tell me what this is?

```
{serializeNulls:falsefactories:[Factory[typeHierarchy=com.google.gson.JsonElement,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25@1626cd8], com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$1@d8130f, com.google.gson.internal.Excluder@1cb79b7, Factory[type=java.lang.String,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13@1a3e88e], Factory[type=java.lang.Integer+int,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7@1f8f4b6], Factory[type=java.lang.Boolean+boolean,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3@18a01be], Factory[type=java.lang.Byte+byte,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$5@17892f9], Factory[type=java.lang.Short+short,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$6@f92fba], Factory[type=java.lang.Long+long,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8@1ac9a62], Factory[type=java.lang.Double+double,adapter=com.google.gson.Gson$3@577d32], Factory[type=java.lang.Float+float,adapter=com.google.gson.Gson$4@1dc64f9], Factory[type=java.lang.Number,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11@11c9201], Factory[type=java.lang.Character+char,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$12@b590a2], Factory[type=java.lang.StringBuilder,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16@2aaa34], Factory[type=java.lang.StringBuffer,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$17@10c5fe9], Factory[type=java.math.BigDecimal,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$14@16cc7de], Factory[type=java.math.BigInteger,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$15@b5e57b], Factory[type=java.net.URL,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$18@1ecf0a7], Factory[type=java.net.URI,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$19@ab85c1], Factory[type=java.util.UUID,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$21@da57c9], Factory[type=java.util.Locale,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$24@b97fd2], Factory[typeHierarchy=java.net.InetAddress,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$20@76ebc2], Factory[type=java.util.BitSet,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$2@17010de], com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter$1@6394e6, Factory[type=java.util.Calendar+java.util.GregorianCalendar,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$23@1c4a703], com.google.gson.internal.bind.TimeTypeAdapter$1@1b0cd6e, com.google.gson.internal.bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter$1@7f168d, com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22@1a1bfc2, com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1@346299, com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$26@1353425, Factory[type=java.lang.Class,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1@1f28052], com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory@692098, com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory@1dae9ba, com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory@126d002, com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory@1225df4],instanceCreators:{}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a stack trace, where/how did you get this message?

Comment: http://webservice-doms.rhcloud.com/rest/user By trying to access my service. Hehe

Comment: This looks to be properly JSON serialized, it looks like it's something internal to your service (as if you return the wrong thing).

Comment: I fixed it. :) I used Gson in a wrong way.

Comment: What was the solution? I am having the same error.